# input type="reset"isn't working in google chrome 17

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, reset

This is my code for a page I'm building. It is a form built using visual C#.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title> Movie Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: -1; font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT', Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;}
        body {background: white url('bg.jpg') top left repeat-x;}
        h1 {color: white; margin-bottom: 8px;}
        #wrapper {margin: 0 auto; width: 450px;}
        #content {margin: 100px 0 20px 0; padding: 40px 20px; border: 10px solid white; width: 380px; background: #4ec0e5;background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%, #3296b6 100%);background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4ec0e5), color-stop(100%,#3296b6));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4ec0e5', endColorstr='#3296b6',GradientType=0 );-moz-border-radius: 52px;border-radius: 52px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;}
        .rqd {color: #f00;}
        #rqdEx {margin-top:3px;color:White;font-size:smaller;font-style:italic;}
        #buttons{margin: 15px;text-align: center;}
        #submit, #reset {-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');background-color:#ededed;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;border:1px solid #dcdcdc;display:inline-block;color:#777777;padding:6px 24px;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;}
        #submit:hover, #reset:hover {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');background-color:#dfdfdf;}
        #ValidationSummary1 ul{list-style: none; margin: 10px 0 0 10px; font-size: smaller;color: white;}
        #ValidationSummary1 li{border-bottom: 1px solid red;}
        #resultLbl{margin: 10px 0 0 10px; font-size: smaller;color: white; font-weight:bold;}
    </style>
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
      <style type="text/css">
        .gradient {
           filter: none;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->    
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content" class="gradient">
            <h1>Movie <strong>Form</strong></h1>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="380px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="45%">
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="fNameLbl" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="fName" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fNameRqd" ControlToValidate="fName" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your first name'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="fNameReg" ControlToValidate="fName" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,40}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your name can be no more than 40 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your name can be no more than 40 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="address1lbl" runat="server" Text="Address Line 1"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="address1Rqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="address1" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your address'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your address"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="address1Reg" ControlToValidate="address1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,120}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your address can be no more than 120 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your address can be no more than 120 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="townlbl" runat="server" Text="Town/City"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="town" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="townRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="town" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Town/City'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Town/City"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="townReg" ControlToValidate="town" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,76}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your Town/City name can be no more than 76 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your Town/City name can be no more than 76 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="postcodelbl" runat="server" Text="Postcode"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="postcode" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="postcodeRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postcode" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Postcode'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Postcode"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="postcodeReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postcode" ValidationExpression="\d{4}" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your Postcode can only be 4 digits long'>" ErrorMessage="Your Postcode can only be 4 digits long"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="emaillbl" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="emailRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your email'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" ValidationExpression="^(?=.{0,100}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter a valid email address less than 100 characters long'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address less than 100 characters long"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="phonelbl" runat="server" Text="Phone No."></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="phoneReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your phone number'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your phone number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="phoneReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" ValidationExpression="\d{0,14}" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your phone number can be no longer than 14 digits'>" ErrorMessage="Your phone number can be no longer than 14 digits"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="doblbl" runat="server" Text="D.O.B"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<span style="font-style: italic; font-size: x-small;">(dd/mm/yyy)</span>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dob" runat="server" Width="140px" CssClass="datePicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="dobRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dob" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Date of Birth'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Date of Birth"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator id="dateValidator" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="dob" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyy'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyy"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="movielbl" runat="server" Text="Favourite Move"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="movie" runat="server" Width="140px">
                            <asp:ListItem>We Bought a Zoo</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>The Breakfast Club</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Puss in Boots</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="movieReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="movie" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please pick a movie'>" ErrorMessage="Please pick a movie"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="genderlbl" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="gender" runat="server" Width="140px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="male">Male</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="female">Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="genderReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="gender" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please pick a gender'>" ErrorMessage="Please pick a gender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table> 
            <div id="rqdEx"><span class="rqd">*</span><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Denotes required fields"></asp:Label></div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" id="reset" />
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="resultLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { } }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the clear button in Chrome 17 it doesn't do anything. Can anyone see anything wrong? I'm not wanting to do it with Javascript if possible

Comment: This jsFiddle works in Chrome 17 for me.  Does it work for you?  http://jsfiddle.net/Yg6fC/

Comment: The Reset button doesn't clear the form it only brings the form back to the original state.  Is your problem that the button is not causing the form to clear, or not bring back to the initial state?

Comment: I found that it works if I haven't pressed submit, but once I've pressed submit it won't. so I think that answers it. :)

Answer (score 1):

reset reloads the page to its initial values and does not sets value to null or zero.
for exp if value in salary box is 20000(as page was loaded) and we edit it to 30000,after pressing reset value in salary box will revert to 20000 not to zero.